# 3D Surface Plot MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am currently working to plot a 3D rectangle on MATLAB. I only have the dimensions of my rectangle "Width", "Length" & "Height". Now I want to plot the rectangle in 3D form using these dimensions. My approach was `mesh` function of MATLAB. I already obtained the corner points of my 3D rectangle using `meshgrid`. My approach is as follows:

```
x1 = [0 length]
x2 = [0 base]
x3 = [0 height] 

[X1, X2, X3] = meshgrid(x1, x2, x3); //this gives all the intersection points of my 3d rectangle

surf(X1,X2,X3);
```

Unfortunately, this method isn't working. So how am I supposed to plot a 3d rectangle from the given dimensions(i.e width, length & height)? The 3d rectangle can start from the origin (0,0,0).

Help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: You can use [`plotcube`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15161-plotcube) from the Matlab File Exchange.

Comment: can you please explain by giving an example

Comment: There are examples shown in the doc of `plotcube`, that should give you a hint